# Count how often second element is second element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column CCC that contains three-letter items. I want to count how often does each letter/element happen as first, second or third element. For example, if I have strings "spr" and "str" I have "s" two times as first letter, "p" one time as second letter, "t" one time as second letter and "r" two times as third letter. In the end I need three dictionaries
Right now I struggle to extract the second letter/element.

```
elements = ["p","b","t","d","k","g","f","v","s","<","z","S","Z","x","G","_","*","m","n","N","r","l","j","h","c"]
counts_C1 = {}
for element in elements:
    counts_C1[element] = df.CCC.str.startswith(element).sum()

counts_C2 = {}
for element in elements:
    counts_C2[element] = 


counts_C3 = {}
for element in elements:
    counts_C3[element] = df.CCC.str.endswith(element).sum()
```

Comment: something like this?  `df.CCC.str[1].eq(element).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You would use .str[position]

So Below is the solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['CCC'] = ['spr','str']

elements = ["p","b","t","d","k","g","f","v","s","<","z","S","Z","x","G","_","*","m","n","N","r","l","j","h","c"]
counts_C1 = {}
for element in elements:
    counts_C1[element] = df.CCC.str.startswith(element).sum()

counts_C2 = {}
for element in elements:
    counts_C2[element] = (df.CCC.str[1] == element).sum()

counts_C3 = {}
for element in elements:
    counts_C3[element] = df.CCC.str.endswith(element).sum()
```